# How can I reference a field in MongoDB without knowing its name?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to find all unique strings of some subdocument in MongoDB, as long as at least one of them contains a certain substring.
These strings are localized though.
I want to have the results for all possible languages.

So, my document would look something like this:

```
{
  ...
  "myLocalizedField": {
    "en": ...,
    "de": ...,
    "cz": ...
...
}
```

I do not know which languages are being used in the DB and not all documents use the same languages.

This is what my current pipeline looks like:

```
[
  {
    $match:
      {
        "I DON'T KNOW": {
          $regex: "my substring",
        },
      },
  },
  {
    $project:
      {
        myLocalizedField: 1,
      },
  },
  {
    $unwind:
      {
        path: "$myLocalizedField",
      },
  },
  {
    $group:
      {
        _id: {
          key: "I DON'T KNOW",
        },
      },
  },
]
```

I am unsure what to put in the `$match` and in the `$group` stages...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$objectToArray` to rescue](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/):

```
[
  {
    $project: { localized: { $objectToArray: "$myLocalizedField" } }
  },
  {
    $unwind:
      {
        path: "$localized",
      },
  },
  {
    $match:
      {
        "localized.v": {
          $regex: "my substring",
        },
      },
  },
  {
    $group:
      {
        _id: {
          key: "$localized.k",
        },
      },
  },
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [$objectToArray](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) operator:

#### Pseudocode

```
INPUT:
{"en":"foo", "de":"bar", "cz":"buz"} 
OUTPUT:
[{"k":"en", "v":"foo"}, {"k":"de", "v":"bar"}, {"k":"cz", "v":"buz"}]
```

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "tmp": {
        "$objectToArray": "$myLocalizedField"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "tmp.v": {
        $regex: "llo"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$tmp"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "tmp.v": {
        $regex: "llo"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fPoAQihcoN3)

**Note:** This solution doesn't scale, since we reshape the document before searching.

I recommend you to store your documents this way:

```
{
  "myLocalizedField": [
    {"k": "en", "v": "Hello world"},
    {"k": "de", "v": "Hallo Welt"},
    {"k": "cz", "v": "Ahoj světe"},
    {"k": "es", "v": "Hola Mundo"},
  ]
}
```

In this way the search is scalable and it is easier to apply [filters](https://mongoplayground.net/p/23LXTywCQ3H).

Comment: Thanks. Pavel Bely was faster, so I'm going to accept his answer though. Regarding changing the schema: that's not really possible, it's a production system and this is a one time investigation

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $set: { myLocalizedField: { $objectToArray: "$myLocalizedField" } } },
   { $match: { "myLocalizedField.v": { $regex: "llo" } } },
   {
      $set: {
         myLocalizedField: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$myLocalizedField",
               cond: { $regexMatch: { input: "$$this.v", regex: "llo" } }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $set: { myLocalizedField: { $arrayToObject: "$myLocalizedField" } } }
])
```

It should be faster than the other solutions, using `$unwind` followed by `$group` is a bit pointless.

As you see, it uses two regex checks. The first one filters all documents where the expression does not exist at all, the second one filter the array elements where string matches.

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8MnI3LhKT45)